# select if typerof vlaue of var is number javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, typeof

I want to get the value of the input with id `ticketNum` and alert that when clicked. I got that working. I also want to compare the number to 10 if the value is a number using `<` and `>`.

The first alert is working fine but the second is not:

```
 function initElement() {
     var p = document.getElementById("sub");
     p.onclick = showAlert;
 };

 function showAlert() {
     var o = document.getElementById("ticketNum").value;
     alert('la valeur de cet input est ' + o);

     if (typeof o === "number") {
         if (o < 10) {
             alert('inferieur a 10');
         } else {
             alert('superieur a 10');
         }
     }
 };
```

Comment: Any time you read a value from a DOM element, it will always be a string. You can coerce it to a number using `parseInt(o)`, `Number(o)`, `+o`, etc.

Comment: There is syntax `var o document.getElementById("ticketNum").value`
Please apply = operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking whether given text input is number or not you can use `isNaN` function and then convert it to number using `Number` function.

Here's sample code snippet based on question -

```js
function initElement() {
  var p = document.getElementById("sub");
  p.onclick = showAlert;
};

function showAlert() {
  var o = document.getElementById("ticketNum").value;
  alert('the input value is ' + o);

  if (!isNaN(o)) {
    if (Number(o) < 10) {
      alert('inferior to 10');
    } else {
      alert('superior to 10');
    }
  }
};

initElement();
```

```html
<input id="ticketNum" type="text" />
<button id="sub">Show Alert</button>
```